# How can UPS turn computer on after it was shut down by power loss?

Tags: power-supply, shutdown, ups

Suppose computer is connected to UPS and UPS is connected to the computer with USB cable. Some software runs on the computer, which is capable to shut it down gracefully on power loss.

Suppose power loss happened. UPS sent a command to the software to shut down, an the computer did it.

Now suppose power supply has returned before charge depleted. So power wasn't loss at computer's end.

How computer can know about it and turn on?

Comment: It depends from specific configuration* but there are so many edge cases, that I would advice other topology: *Add something which is dependent on regular power and configure it to send WakeOnLan packet to your computer (with added delay to allow computer to shut down gracefully if it was in this process at the moment)*. You can use some other computer (with After Power Loss: Always On), Arduino or any other device capable to send WoL packets i.e.: smart home drivers. *Your post lacks device model.

Comment: `WakeOnLan` works even less reliable than BIOS "turn on", so it is not an option.

Comment: APC software can instruct the UPS to turn off shortly after the PC has shut down. Other UPS models could also support this.

Comment: @DanielB which UPS-es do this? How to distinguish?

Comment: No idea. _Apcupsd_ calls this feature “killpower”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ordinary UPS units do not turn a computer back on. Mostly what I see is that it is the computer UPS control software that shuts down the machine.

If you are present, just turn it on.  This is what I do. Very simple.

If you are not present, try Wake on LAN and start it remotely that way.

I use the middle method because someone is often around to turn on the computer(s).

Comment: If I was present, I was also able to turn computer off. There was no need to do this automatically.

Comment: Is it possible to have "extraordinary" UPS to turn computer on?

Comment: Most UPS units I see (I use APC myself) do not do this.  But as I say, always someone around.

Comment: If such UPS exist, how could it turn on a computer?

Comment: I have not seen one that will turn on  a PC after shutdown.

Answer (score 3):

Most computers have an "*After Power Loss*" configuration option in the BIOS, generally with the following options:

- Stay off
- Last state
- Turn on

If you need / want your computer to automatically power up after the power supply returns, then select the "*turn on*" option (or words to that effect).

You will also need to confirm that the UPS will re-power its outputs after the power returns.

The difficult situation is when the power loss occurs, the UPS instructs a clean shutdown, and then the power returns before the UPS turns its outputs off. In this situation, the computer won't observe the power loss and return, and therefore cannot turn itself back on again... With many computers you can set a "*wake on alarm*" event that is facilitated by the BIOS and RTC - you could use this to schedule an alarm and thus power-up 15 minutes from now (or another time that exceeds the UPS's runtime).

On Linux, you can set such an alarm with the following command:

```bash
rtcwake --mode no --utc --date "$(date -d '30 mins' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')"
```

Comment: Only last paragpraph of your answer is relating to the question. So, the answer is "no way" in short?

Comment: No, I'd suggest looking into setting a wake alarm that will catch this situation. You'll inevitably see some downtime, but you won't need to be physically present to resolve it (zero downtime is an unrealistic goal). I've updated my answer with an example command.

Comment: I use power on when restored, along with a wifi control on the outlet. I can remote into the computer, perform ordinary tasks, perform ordinary shut-down, then power off the wifi control. Once the control is powered on, the computer restarts. A UPS powering back on would be able to perform the same.